# Winforms DataGridView SQL compact CRUD example

Tags: winforms, datagridview, sql-server-ce

I have a very simple table with two string columns marked unique.  Can anyone tell me how to wire up the datagridview to allow the most basic crud operations.  I intend to use only the grid and no additional controls.  This means having a link column for the delete operation.

I have tried a million iterations of having data tables, binding sources, data adapters, command builders..

Many thanks.

```
void dataGridView1_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e)
{

}

private void bindingSource_PositionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        // if the user moves to a new row, check if the 
        // last row was changed
        BindingSource thisBindingSource =
          (BindingSource)sender;

        DataRow ThisDataRow =
          ((DataRowView)thisBindingSource.Current).Row;
        if (ThisDataRow == _lastDataRow)
        {
            // we need to avoid to write a datarow to the 
            // database when it is still processed. Otherwise
            // we get a problem with the event handling of 
            //the DataTable.
            throw new InvalidOperationException("It seems the" +
              " PositionChanged event was fired twice for" +
              " the same row");
        }

        UpdateRowToDatabase();
        // track the current row for next 
        // PositionChanged event
        _lastDataRow = ThisDataRow;
    }

    private void UpdateRowToDatabase()
    {   
        if (_lastDataRow != null)
        {
            if (_lastDataRow.RowState == DataRowState.Modified
                || _lastDataRow.RowState == DataRowState.Added
                || _lastDataRow.RowState == DataRowState.Deleted)
            {
                DataRow[] rows = new DataRow[1];
                rows[0] = _lastDataRow;
                _dataAdapter.Update(rows);
            }
        }
    }        

void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Click Col: {0} Row:{1}", e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex));

        if (!_edit && e.ColumnIndex == 0)
        {
            if (e.RowIndex < _dataTable.Rows.Count)
            {
                DataRow[] rows = new DataRow[1];
                rows[0] = _dataTable.Rows[e.RowIndex];
                _bindingSource.RemoveCurrent();
                _dataAdapter.Update(rows);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the ResultSetGrid class in the CodePlex project here: http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/77500#1210725

Comment: This has moved me forward no end, Thank you.  I still have an issue with deleting records.

Comment: Your table must have a primary key - does it?

Comment: Yes I had a primary key, In the end I just used the navigator control which has a delete button on it.